# Free realtime email notifier for RSS feeds

Tags: gratis, web-apps, email, rss

I have never used RSS and would not like to start using an RSS client - it's just one more thing to keep track of. However, I find myself wishing to subscribe to notifications from a service that only offers them via an RSS feed (namely, the AWS status monitor at http://status.aws.amazon.com/, which offers a bunch of RSS feeds to monitor status updates for their various services).

The simplest way for me to receive this content would simply be to receive email notifications whenever anything is published on any of the RSS feeds I'm interested in. How can I do this?

An ideal solution will:

- Be free
- Guarantee delivery of an email notification within a few minutes of a post being published to the feed

So far I have found a couple of online tools that come *close* to offering what I want:

- [Blogtrottr](https://blogtrottr.com/), which has paid service that does what I want and a free service that almost does what I want but [only polls non-push feeds for updates once per hour](https://blogtrottr.com/help/#update_frequency).
- [Feed2Mail](http://www.feed2mail.com/), which is free but pretty much completely undocumented; I have no idea whether it checks for updates as frequently as I want.

Is there anything out there that comes closer to my desired objectives than the tools above?

Comment: Many email clients already support RSS feeds. Why not use them to subscribe instead of having the feed pass through another app then back to your email?

Comment: @Timmy interesting. I didn't know that and it may help some people - but I use Gmail's web client so it's no help to me unless I'm willing to change my email client.

Answer (score 4):

Since you are specific to GMail I found a specific to GMail description [here](http://fieldguide.gizmodo.com/turn-gmail-into-an-rss-reader-with-ifttt-1582552035) but it would work regardless of your email client:

1. Sign up to [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com/) - it is **free**.
2. Click the `Create` button at the top to start building a recipe. Choose `Feed` as the trigger channel then pick New feed item. Enter your RSS link — such as http://status.aws.amazon.com/rss/appstream-us-east-1.rss —and click `Create Trigger`.
3. Select `Email` as your action channel (do **not** select `Gmail` at this point).
4. Select `Send me an email` as the action (it should be the only option available) and you can customize the layout of the emails you receive.
5. Click the plus symbol to the right to add new feed elements.
6. Tailor as necessary and repeat for each feed.

Each time the feed pushes out a notification IFTTT will receive it and send your email within a very short time - how long it takes you to get it is up to a number of other factors.

***Note:*** *This is a web only solution - you do **not** have to have an android device to use IFTTT.*

Answer (score 1):

There's also [rss2email](http://www.allthingsrss.com/rss2email/), which is a Python-Program available for Linux, OS X and Windows.